# MySQL IF Statement change value on the fly?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm not even sure if this is quite possible to do with MySQL, but I hope it is.

OK so i have this SQL command

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE $WhereCondition ORDER BY ListStyle
```

> As an example of the data in the ListStyle I might have
>
> 2000    3000  3700    3800

What I'm hoping to do is use some kind of if statement in the SQL that will allow me to check other fields in a result row so that I can change the value of the ListStyle before I use that in the page to order it appropriately.

So for instance I have fields a, b and c. Now if a and b are NOT empty and c = 100 and the ListStyle = 3700, I want to change the value of ListStyle to 3699 so that when I print out a result loop, rows that match the condition `( a != '', b != '', c = 100 and ListStyle = 3700)` will then be shown above the rows that have the ListStyle of 3700

I can't simply edit the data in the database, even though that would be an easy solution. The data has to stay as it is.

I originally tried doing this in php. While its easy enough to change the value of the ListStyle using if statements, I don't know of an easy way to then actually order my results without sticking everything into an array and then sorting through it. I really don't want to do that as it would mean re-writing a lot of code, which is why I'm hoping this is all possible to do in MySQL.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you please give an example of data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE $WhereCondition ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN ( a = 0, b = 0, c = 100 and ListStyle = 3700)  THEN 1
        WHEN ( a = 10, b = 20, c = 200 and ListStyle = 3400) THEN 2
        ELSE 10
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IF` or `CASE` inside the ORDER BY statement like

```
...
ORDER BY
  IF(condition1, then_value, else_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT a,b,c, IF($condition, 3700, 3699) AS order WHERE $whereCondition ORDER BY order
```

Expressing $condition in MySQL might be tedious, but I think it's possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: But the trigger would have to change the data, and that's not allowed.